# Parse id to SQL primary key field

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

Im parsing simple json data with fields: `id, name, location` e.t.c from server and I want to save it in to a sqllite db. In the db i have two tables:

`one(id, name, location_id, ....)`

`second(id, location_name, lat, lon, ...)`

and a select with an inner join.

So when i fill the db from json, what is the preferred way to write the id from json to a table pramary key, OR use autoinc primary key and parse json data without id's.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It really depends on how you want to use the data. Ask yourself, if you had some data already in these tables how would you then use this data ? Would importing the ID's from the JSON provide a vital part ? Or can they just be ignored and have auto generated IDs.

Comment: structure the data first - very important, define your keys from the relations in the system, after all what do the keys identify, normalise the datastructures first and then decide whether you want an auto inc id pk 
 define the entity's first.

Comment: I think that good idea use ids from json structure, because it is already unique key with ready links in other data arrays. But Im not sure how fast sql db will work with key from json - its very long value, about 10-15 digits..